# I need to replace whole html in an iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an Iframe. From my page I want to replace whole html inside iframe with some new html that I generated from builder.
I checked other solutions on stackoverflow, But in those questions they asking to replace particular element or body ot head but I need to replace whole html.
Any Idea?

New Notes:
Let say my code is something like this:

```
var iframeTemp = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframeTemp.setAttribute('id','tempIframeM');
        iframeTemp.setAttribute('srcdoc', blck.frameContent);
        $('.tempIframeContainer').append(iframeTemp);
        var tempIframeD = $('#tempIframeM').contentWindow || ( $('#tempIframeM').contentDocument || $('#tempIframeM').contentDocument);
        // console.log("Iframe content is as follows: ", this.sandbox ,$('#' + this.sandbox).contents(), iframeTemp);
        console.log("Temporary iframe content is: ", $(tempIframeD).contents().find('body').html());
```

Now $(tempIframeD).contents().find('body').html() in console.log gives undefined

Comment: If it's inside an Iframe, i suppose that iframe as an id. So you should be able to load you html in a js variable then do something like $(""MyIframe").html(MyHtml);

Comment: I tried that but that don't work.

Comment: Well, i want to be sure, you want to replace the whole html of the iFrame or the whole html of the file ? Can you post some code to see what's going on ?

Comment: Yes I want to replace whole html of iframe with the html I have saved in my database(that I have already fetched in my view).

var newHtml = '<html><body><h1>My Title</h1></body></html>';
var iframe = $('frame#myframe');
iframe.html(newHtml);

Comment: let's try something like that : $(youriframe).contents().find('html').html('your content here'); But then it will depends on your browser.

Comment: I tried this solution as well. But it didn't worked as well.

Comment: Well sorry, i need to see your html and jQuery. If you could edit your post with such infos, it will be great.

Comment: Is the iframe source on the same domain as your script? If not, you might not be able to load its contents due [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: I am adding html through attribute srcdoc

iframeTemp.setAttribute('srcdoc', blck.frameContent);

and blck.frameContent contains whole html